# What is the session name in joomla?

Tags: joomla

Hi guys I've download the latest version of joomla and I'm trying to analyze it's session but I had a problem with the session name and  getsession() .

Because all the sessions name is (4109fdb14b2662cce79b856bc4d72ed3)

So my question is where did this value come from?
and one more thing ... where is getsession defined?

Comment: The places to understand this process are: JSession, JUser, JFactory and JApplication. When you have looked at the files if you have questions that are more detailed perhaps you can modify your question. https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/session/session.php#L831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$session_name = JFactory::getSession()->getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually Joomla relies on PHP to handle the session id / session.

See also [session_id().](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

As pointed out in comments, have a look the the `JSession` class.